# Rowstyle gridview

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I want to ask a question about devexpress gridview.I have a gridview and I want to do like that if gridview's any columns has 1 value then that column's color will be yellow.I hope I could explain what i want to do,Thank you for your helps

Comment: And what doesn't work? Maybe some code of your implementation, some screenshots???

Comment: I also don't know what is problem?

Comment: I am constantly investigating problems

Comment: private void GridView2_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column == RemainDays)
            {
                if (GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.ListSourceRowIndex, GridView2.Columns["ExtendedCheck"]) == "")
                {
                    return;
                }

Comment: if (mExtendedCheck == "Checked")
                {
                    if (GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.ListSourceRowIndex, GridView2.Columns["ExtendedUntil"]) == "")
                    {
                        return;
                    }

Comment: DateTime mExtendedUntil = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.ListSourceRowIndex, GridView2.Columns["ExtendedUntil"]));
                    int mFarkExtended = Convert.ToInt32(DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateTime.Now.Date, mExtendedUntil, (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek)Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear)Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1));
                    e.Value = mFarkExtended;
                }

Comment: else
                {
                    if (GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.ListSourceRowIndex, GridView2.Columns["ValidUntil"]) == "")
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    DateTime mValidUntil = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.ListSourceRowIndex, GridView2.Columns["ValidUntil"]));

Comment: int mFark = Convert.ToInt32(DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateTime.Now.Date, mValidUntil, (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek)Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear)Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1));
                    e.Value = mFark;
                }

Comment: public void GridView2_RowStyle(System.Object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
  {
            
            String mExtendedCheck = GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, GridView2.Columns["ExtendedCheck"]);

            if (mExtendedCheck == "Checked")
            {
                if (GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, GridView2.Columns["ExtendedUntil"]) == "")
                {
                    return;
                }

Comment: int mFarkExtended = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle,gridColumn3));
                if (mFarkExtended <= 0)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;}

Comment: else if (mFarkExtended >= 1 & mFarkExtended <= 15)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                   
                }

Comment: else if (mFarkExtended >= 1 & mFarkExtended <= 60)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (GridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, GridView2.Columns["ValidUntil"]) == "")
                {
                    return;
                }

Comment: int mFark = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle,gridColumn3));
                if (mFark <= 0)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                 
                }
                else if (mFark >= 1 & mFark <= 15)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                   
                }

Comment: else if (mFark >= 1 & mFark <= 60)
                {
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                }

Comment: I have a RemaindDays columns and it is unbound columns and the type is int

Comment: @Mustafa Can u post your code in normal formatted style in your question, not in comments? We`ll be pleased

Comment: @galakt I have reached myquestion limit in this site.how can you solve my problem?

Comment: @Mustafa Edit this question

Comment: @galakt do  u have gmail? if u have can u tell me? and I'll send my code to you

Comment: @Mustafa What do you mean, when you say "does not work correctly"?

Comment: I have a gridview and making a grouping there so it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Please post code in your question for better understanding and problem solving.

Comment: @RuchiRahulDoshi I also posted code in my question

Comment: @RuchiRahulDoshi I edited my codes.Here is my code and I want to do that I calculated remain days and as you see I have created a unbound columns that column name is RemainDays then I have a girdview that gridview doing grouping.and some data does not work correctly I think that problem may be due to grouping.But I don't know what's problem? Thank you all for your helps